# Safety stock when there is uncertainty in order completion

Tags: reference-request, inventory, uncertainty

Safety stocks account for uncertainty both on demand and provider lead times, but never mention how to include the effect of incomplete orders. For example, what would happen if a provider always delivers on time but on average orders have 50% of the promised quantity?

I couldn't find any papers that include this effect.

Answer (score 9):

What you’re describing is known as **inventory optimization under yield uncertainty.** There is quite a bit of literature on it. Two relevant literature reviews are [Yano and Lee (*OR* 1995)](https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.43.2.311) and [Grosfeld-Nir and Gerchak (*AOR* 2004)](https://doi.org/10.1023/B:ANOR.0000012275.01260.f5).

Yield uncertainty is only one type of supply uncertainty. A closely related form is disruptions; my students and I wrote a review paper on this topic a few years ago ([Snyder, et al., *IIET* 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/0740817X.2015.1067735)).

We discuss inventory models with both yield uncertainty and disruptions in [our textbook](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Fundamentals+of+Supply+Chain+Theory%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781119024842), if that helps.